# Magento 2 : Override Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeList.php

Tags: magento2

Is their anyway we can override
Override `Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeList` class in module ?

Comment: what do you need to override from that class?

Comment: Hello, actually i am creating a module that checks the invalidated cache & refresh it.

i want to override this class so i can refresh cache which are invalidated.

Answer (score 0):

As long as there is a public method that you need to override, then a plugin can do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually i want to call that method that clears the cache.
So just overriding the method will not be enough.

Comment: out of curiosity - did you try using preference mechanism? (not sure if it works)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and let me know if this will help or not.

app\code\Module\ModuleName\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeList" type="Module\ModuleName\Framework\App\Cache\TypeList" />
</config>
```

Module\ModuleName\Framework\App\Cache\TypeList.php

```
<?php
namespace Module\ModuleName\Framework\App\Cache;

/**
* Message model factory
*/
class TypeList extends \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeList
{
/* You can add or edit anything in this file */
}
```

Comment: Hello Nits, is their any way i can call this TypelIst class's function in my controller file ?

the purpose is to make an ajax request to controller & check for invalidated cache & clean it.

Comment: Let me know your thoughts on this if any, that would be helpful